# C++ Constructor Car Class

Tags: c++, performance, function, object, constructor

**Hi all, I am having some trouble with the below assignment. When I run the code, everything appears to work, but the numbers that I get in the print out are not accurate. Not sure if it is the constructor I have that is set up wrong or what. I've just been banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out. Any help/advice would be much appreciated!**

**Here is the assignment text:**

*Car Class Instructions:* Write a class named 'Car' that has the following member variables:

year. An int that holds the car's model year.

make. A string object that holds the make of the car.

speed. An int object that holds the car's current speed.

In addition, the class should have the following member functions:

Constructor. The constructor should accept the car's year and make member variables. The constructor should initialize these values to the object's year and make member variables. The constructor should initialize the speed member variable to 0.

Accessors. Appropriate accessor functions should be created to allow values to be retrieved from an object's year, make and speed member variables.

Accelerate. The accelerate function should add 5 to the speed member variable each time it is called.

Brake. THe brake function should subtract 5 from the speed member variable each time it is called. Demonstrate the class in a program that creates a Car object, and then calls the accelerate function five times. After each call to the accelerate function, get the current speed of the car and display it. Then, call the brake function 5 times. After each call to the brake function, get the current speed of the car and display it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Car
{
  private:
    int year;
    string make;
    int speed;

  public:
    Car(int, string, int);
    int getSpeed();
    int getModel();
    void accelerate();
    void brake();


};

int Car::getSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}

Car::Car(int year, string make, int speed = 0 )
{
}

void Car::accelerate()
{
    speed +=5;
}

void Car::brake()
{
    if( speed > 5 )
        speed -=5;
    else speed = 0 ;
}


int main ()
{
    int year;
    string make;
    cout << "Please enter the model year of the car.\n";
    cin >> year ;
    cout << "Please enter the make of the car.\n";
    cin >> make ;

    Car myCar(year,make);
    int i = 0;
    for (; i<5; ++i)
    {
        myCar.accelerate();
        cout << "Accelerating.\n" << "The current speed of the car is: " << myCar.getSpeed()<<endl;
    }

    {
        int j = 0;
        for (; j<5; ++j)
        {
            myCar.brake();
            cout << "Decelerating.\n" << "The current speed of the car is: " << myCar.getSpeed()<<endl;
        }

        return (0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the result when you use a *debugger*?  Which statement is the culprit?  This would be a good project for learning to use a debugger.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I'm using X-Code, not seeing a way to use a debugger in that application. There are no error messages when I run the code.

Comment: @IainKilpatrick Even without a debugger, you could place print statements to see what's going on inside your program during runtime. Learning to debug is essential to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constructor

```
Car::Car(int year, string make, int speed = 0 )
{
}
```

initialize nothing. It has an empty body and neither initializer member list. Moreover according to the assignment the constructor has to have two parameters.

It can look the following way

Inside the class definition

```
inline Car( int year, std::string & make );
```

and the definition of the constructor itself

```
Car::Car( int year, const std::string make ) : year( year ), make( make ), speed( 0 )
{
}
```

The accessors can be declared like

```
int getYear() const;
int getSpeed() const;
const std::string & getModel() const;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor

```
Car::Car(int year, string make, int speed = 0 )
{
}
```

is not doing what you describe.   The three parameters (`year`, `make`, and `speed`) have the same names as `Car`s members, but are separate variables.

The result is that `Car`s members are default constructed, and the values passed by `main()` are effectively ignored.

To make things clearer, give the arguments different names, and initialise the members in an initialiser list.

```
Car::Car(int y, string m, int s) : year(y), make(m), speed(s)
{
}
```

It is permissible for the arguments to have the same names as class members, but this tends to be harder to read i.e. it is easier to misunderstand what the code is doing.   In your case, you believe that giving the parameters the same name as class members serves to initialise the class members, and that is flat-out wrong.   Either way, the constructor needs to explicitly initialise the members using the parameters, otherwise the class members receive default values (not the ones passed).

Also, if you want an argument with a default value, specify it in the definition of the class, not in the definition of the constructor.  For example;

```
class Car
{
      public:

          Car(int, std::string, int = 0);
};

Car::Car(int y, string m, int s) : year(y), make(m), speed(s)
{
}
```

That makes things easier, particularly if the class definition is in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <iostream>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    double getaccelarate(double &, double &);
    double getbrake(double &, double &);
    double getcruise(double &, double &);
    void outputStatusHeader();
    void demo();
    double updateDistanceTraveled(double &, double &);
    int delta = 5;
    //double brakee = 0;


    double previousSpeed = 0;
    double currentSpeed = 0;


    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        char  command;
        //The amount of elapsed time for each calculation interval 
    (fixed at 1 second)
        const int timeInterval = 1;


        //double currentSpeed=0;
        //convert into the distance travelled by feet
        int    totalFeetTraveled = 0;
        //the average speed travel
        int averageSpeed = 0;


        //double previousSpeed =0;
        int averageSpeed_FeetPerSecond = 0;
        int  intervalFeetTraveled = 0;
        int speed = 0;
        //the amount of time that the time will increase by
        //const int delta= 5;




        while (true)
        {
                cout << "Command:";
                cin >> command;
                switch (command)
            {


            case 'a':
               //double accelarate;
                double speed;
                speed = getaccelarate(currentSpeed, previousSpeed);
              //cout << getaccelarate;
                cout << "Accelerate"<<setw(20)<<"Accelerating"<<setw(5);
                cout << speed;
                double conve;
                conve = updateDistanceTraveled(previousSpeed, 
    currentSpeed);
                    cout <<setw(10)<<setprecision(3)<<conve<<endl;

                //updateDistanceTraveled(previousSpeed,currentSpeed);
                break;





            case 'b':
                 double brake;
                 brake = getbrake(previousSpeed, currentSpeed);
                 cout << "Brake" <<setw(20)<<"Braking"<<setw(5);
                 cout << brake; 
                //double brake1 = 0;
                //brake1 = updateDistanceTraveled(previousSpeed, 
                 currentSpeed);
                 cout << setw(10) << setprecision(3) << conve << endl;




                break;

            case 'c':
                 double cruise;
                 cruise = getcruise(previousSpeed, currentSpeed);
                 cout << "Cruise" << setw(20) << "Cruising" << setw(5);
                 cout << cruise;
                 cout << setw(10) << setprecision(3) << conve << endl;


            break;




        case 'h':
            outputStatusHeader();
            break;

        case 'd':

            demo();

            break;
        case 'q':
            cout << " Exit program";
            exit(1);

            break;

        default:
            cout << "Invalid command" << endl; 
            break;
        }



    }




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//converting mph to feet perhours
double updateDistanceTraveled(double &previousSpeed,double &currentSpeed)
{
    //getaccelarate(previousSpeed, currentSpeed);
    double averageSpeed = 0; 
    double averageSpeed_FeetPerSecond = 0; 
    double intervalFeetTraveled=0;
    //double totalFeetTraveled=0;
    const int timeInterval = 1;

    averageSpeed = (previousSpeed + currentSpeed) / 2;
    averageSpeed_FeetPerSecond = averageSpeed * 5280.0 / 3600.0;
    intervalFeetTraveled = averageSpeed_FeetPerSecond * timeInterval;
    return intervalFeetTraveled;
    /*totalFeetTraveled = totalFeetTraveled + intervalFeetTraveled;
    return totalFeetTraveled;*/
}

//to decrease speed
double getbrake(double &previousSpeed, double &currentSpeed)
{



    previousSpeed = currentSpeed;
    currentSpeed -= delta;

    return currentSpeed;


}
//to increase speed
double getaccelarate(double &previousSpeed, double &currentSpeed)
{


    previousSpeed = currentSpeed;
    currentSpeed = currentSpeed + delta;
    return currentSpeed;


}

// to stay in current speed
double getcruise(double &previousSpeed, double &currentSpeed)
{
    previousSpeed = currentSpeed;
    return previousSpeed;

}
//unfinished demo

void demo()

{

    cout << "Function Current State Current Speed Interval Distance 
    Total Feet (and miles) traveled" << endl;

    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    for (int x = 1; x < 4; x++)
    {
        double speed;
        speed = getaccelarate(currentSpeed, previousSpeed);
        //cout << getaccelarate;
        cout << "Accelerate" << setw(20) << "Accelerating" << setw(5);
        cout << speed;
        double conve;
        conve = updateDistanceTraveled(previousSpeed, currentSpeed);
        cout << setw(10) << setprecision(3) << conve << endl;

    }

}

//for supported commands
void outputStatusHeader()

{

    cout << " supported commands\n"
        << " a         accelerate\n"
        << " b         brake\n"
        << " c         cruise\n"
        << " d         demo\n"
        << " h         print this help text\n"
        << " q         quit(end the  program)"
        << endl;

}

{

        cout << " supported commands\n"
            << " a         accelerate\n"
            << " b         brake\n"
            << " c         cruise\n"
            << " d         demo\n"
            << " h         print this help text\n"
            << " q         quit(end the  program)"
            << endl;
```

}